# after a system failure, reinstalling ubuntu. only 2.90G of ram out of 8G is seen

Tags: boot, server, ram

after my server died and having to reinstall Ubuntu server 19.04, There is only 2.90 GB of my RAM that Linux can see and not my whole 8 GB like before... despite me changing the sticks of RAM from dual channel to single channel. slots ABAB.

They're both 4 GB modules and my Bios reads a proper 8192 MB, I know my system takes some memory for the iGPU but not entire chunks! It's a server I SSH into for development and hosting services.

This happened after  what I believe `busybox` was tripped and kept coming up on boot, I don't have a log of what happened but I recall I was missing `init` somewhere in my `rc.d` I think. My harddrive is also very old (about 10 years old) which I replaced with a new one, same issue of 2.90 GB.

`free -m` shows only 2.9 GB for both swap and main mem.

`lshw` shows all sticks of RAM present in the correct slots, a total of 8 GB

I am very confused as to how this could have happened... and even on a fresh install (yes I reseated the RAM multiple times to see if it was faulty. and ran a memtest. all came back fine) I'm sure I installed an x64 OS too, which seems odd why it wouldn't see all 8 GB now when it saw it before the failure

output of `lsb`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

output of `cmdline`

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-32-generic root=UUID=7d120bf8-27bf-46de-83cc-50bc6b9f19fc ro
```

output of `memtotal`

```
MemTotal:        3038856 kB
```

output of `uname`

```
Linux a123 5.0.0-32-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 02:06:48 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

output of `free -m`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2967         166        2062           1         739        2574
Swap:          2966           0        2966
```

output of `dmesg | grep "Memory"`

```
[    0.058346] Memory: 2916468K/3183812K available (14339K kernel code, 2335K rwdata, 4448K rodata, 2588K init, 5192K bss, 267344K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.224591] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
```

output of `dmidecode` for memory

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 1
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: <BAD INDEX>
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: 1600 CL9 Series
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 2
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: <BAD INDEX>
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: 1600 CL9 Series
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 3
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL B
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer2
    Serial Number: A1_SerialNum2
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum2
    Part Number: A1_PartNum2
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x002D
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 4
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL B
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer3
    Serial Number: A1_SerialNum3
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum3
    Part Number: A1_PartNum3
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lsb_release -a will show you your os description and release information

uname -a will show you your kernel build and version to tell you for sure if you are addressing 64-bits

cat /proc/cmdline will show you your kernel command line parameters given for the current booted system

Also,  cat /proc/meminfo |grep MemTotal will give you your installed memory as well.

Run memtest and verify the RAM is good.

Comment: added more information.

Comment: Has any OS with your now current motherboard firmware RAM combination seen all 8GB? Can you please do a: dmesg | grep -i mem

Comment: as well as a: glxinfo | egrep -i 'device|memory'

Comment: If you ran memtest and it came up with no problems, may I assume the memtest kernel detected the correct 8GB?

Comment: Unfortunately the system ram in memtest shows 3149MB yet sees the two modules. the ram I found out is dead yet can still provide _some_ use... just not useful